# phonegap build vs phonegap CLI file size reduction

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

i have an app that uses two phonegap plugins.. the social media plugin and the admob plugin.

i have build my app with CLI and signed it using the following commands:

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore my-release-key.keystore HelloWorld-release-unsigned.apk alias_name
```

and

```
zipalign -v 4 HelloWorld-release-unsigned.apk HelloWorld.apk
```

the app created has a size of 5MB

and when i use the cloud hosted phonegap build service i get an app that has a file size of 3.5MB

**what is causing the increased file size and how can i reduce it.**

I am not changing any code or plugin i am using the same app just build via two different methods

Comment: you can have a look at the [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26167023/reduce-cordova-apks-size#comment41024391_26167023) that I had commented on.

Comment: ok great i did it and this now works..but i want to ask one more thing..what about the config.xml file at what level should the config.xml file be..for the cloud build service i am used to include it inside the "www" folder..for the cli it should be at the same level of the "www" folder..is that correct?