# Remove x86 support from cordova android build for reducing size of .apk

Tags: android, cordova, apk

We are trying to reduce the apk file size. As we are not supporting x86 devices,  we want to remove x86 supported libraries from apk so that it will reduce the apk size.

I am not able to find how to delete those lib files. 
Can anyone guide me for same.

Thanks,

Supriya

Comment: u wan to a reduce .apk file size ?

Comment: refer this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26167023/reduce-cordova-apks-size